# Openpyxl 2.3.2 Change Tab Color/Fit To Page Properties?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to modify an excel spreadsheet to alter the colors of the tabs using Openpyxl 2.3.2 (using Anaconda), but can't seem to get the code to work. I am using the following code, where bdws is a worksheet already in the workbook, and bdws2 is a worksheet I added later.

I can't get either of the sheets to change color.

As well, I can't seem to adjust other page properties like `fitToPage`, using the same worksheets. Just wondering if anyone might know why that is.

```
bdwb = load_workbook(checkFileName(finalBDFileName))
bdws = bdwb[finalBDSheetName]
bdws.sheet_properties.tabcolor ='FFFF00'
bdws.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
bdws2.sheet_properties.tabcolor = 'FF00FF'
bdws2.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
bdwb.save("new bd.xlsx")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to capitalize your Color :)

```
bdws.sheet_properties.tabColor ='FFFF00'
bdws.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
bdws2.sheet_properties.tabColor = 'FF00FF'
bdws2.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
```

should do it for you.

Comment: I actually meant to go back and correct this; I used a different way of achieving the same result where I assigned the `sheet_properties` to an object and then modified it, and then reassigned it. I used that before for something else because that was the only way it worked, and it worked again. I still haven't been able to get the `pageSetupPr` but I just set the columns/rows manually for now.